# AzureServiceTokenProvider Exception: Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. An error occurred while sending the request

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to use User Defined MSI to gain authentication token and then connect to SQL Database.

Steps I see so far;

1. Create a User Defined Managed Identity --> **DONE**.
2. Get Authentication Token using AzureServiceTokenProvider --> **This is where I get error/exception**.
3. Use the Authentication Token received using AzureServiceTokenProvider into SQLConnection.
4. Carry out ADO.Net or EF operations.

I have created a User Defined Managed Identity in my Azure Subscription. I then proceeded to write a simple code to gain access token using AzureServiceTokenProvider. Code is as follows;

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            //var tokenProviderConnectionString = "RunAs=Developer; DeveloperTool=VisualStudio";
            var tokenProviderConnectionString = "RunAs=App;AppId=bbda13b3-b948-4d02-91bb-31f198729887";

            //var azureResource = "https://management.azure.com/";
            var azureResource = "https://database.windows.net/";


            Console.WriteLine("Attempting to gain access token from Azure...");
            var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider(tokenProviderConnectionString);
            string accessToken = azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync(azureResource, "<<My Tenant ID>>").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Console.WriteLine("Successful");
            Console.WriteLine($"Access Token: {accessToken}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

I get an error on `string accessToken = azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync(azureResource, "89cda43f-eb76-413b-bcbf-5c9b17542338").GetAwaiter().GetResult();`.

Exception is

```
Parameters: Connection String: RunAs=App;AppId=bbda13b3-b948-4d02-91bb-31f198729887, Resource: https://database.windows.net/, Authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<<My Tenant ID>>. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Access token could not be acquired. An error occurred while sending the request.
```

If I use `var tokenProviderConnectionString = "RunAs=Developer; DeveloperTool=VisualStudio";` as a connection string, then I am able to get an access token as it is using my Visual Studio Login as an MSI.
But when I use `var tokenProviderConnectionString = "RunAs=App;AppId=bbda13b3-b948-4d02-91bb-31f198729887";` I get the exception mentioned above. I think probably there is a bug in AzureServiceTokenProvider or I am missing something in the request.

Any pointers?

Comment: Do you have update on your question?

Answer (score -1):

You need to login to Azure using that AppId and the password

az login --service-principal --tenant xxx --username bbda13b3-b948-4d02-91bb-31f198729887 --password xxx

Then when the AzureServiceTokenProvider requests a token it will be valid.